# Finding a suitable matrix to solve equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find a matrix $T$ such that it satisfies the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix} =T^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix} T$$

As well as: $$\begin{bmatrix}e^{{2 \pi i}/3} & 0\\0 & e^{{4 \pi i}/3}\end{bmatrix} =T^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi/3) & -\sin(2\pi /3)\\ \sin(2\pi /3) & \cos(2\pi /3)\end{bmatrix} T$$

Comment: Did you mean for the last matrix to be $\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi/3) & -\sin(2\pi/3)\\ \sin(2\pi/3) & \cos(2\pi/3)\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 yes sorry, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @NoChance Could you please explain?

Comment: Solutions to the first equation are:

Try $T = \lambda \begin{vmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{vmatrix}$ or $T = \mu \begin{vmatrix} -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \\ \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \end{vmatrix}$

Comment: @Peter also scalar multiples of this matrix are solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$T=\pmatrix{i&1\\1&i}$$ satisfies both equations.

Comment: How did you get the result? I ask because I tried for it myself, but failed.

Comment: I diagonalized the matrix given in the second equation at the right side. I got $$\pmatrix{I&-I\\1&1}$$. Then, I multiplied the second eigenvector, such that I got the form $\pmatrix{u&v\\v&u}$

Comment: Excuse me if this looks like a stupid question, but notations are sometimes *very* different. What is $I$? I use this symbol, sometimes, as the identity matrix, which makes no sense in this context, nor for any other matrix (of dim>1).

Comment: OK, I should have used $i$ as in the answer. $I$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will spend the rest of the day by figuring out why I failed to do the same thing on the first equation.

Comment: To solve the first equation, I did not diagonalize, I solved the equation $\pmatrix{u&v\\w&x}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{u&v\\w&x}$ and noticed that this implies $u=x$ and $v=w$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and note that we have
$PT=TP$. If we let $T=\begin{bmatrix}a &b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, we see that
this gives $a=d,c=b$, so $T$ has the form $T=\begin{bmatrix}a &b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$.

If $T$ is a solution it is easy to see that $\lambda T$ is a solution for
$\lambda \neq 0$, so we can take $T$ to have the form
$T = \begin{bmatrix}1 &t\\t&1\end{bmatrix}$.

The second equation can be written as
$T \begin{bmatrix}e^{{{2 \pi i} \over 3}} & 0\\0 & e^{{{4 \pi i} \over 3}}\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}\cos({{2 \pi i} \over 3}) & -\sin({{2 \pi i} \over 3})\\ \sin({{2 \pi i} \over 3}) & \cos({{2 \pi i} \over 3})\end{bmatrix} T$. Computing the $(1,1)$ entry gives
$e^{{{2 \pi i} \over 3}} = \cos({{2 \pi i} \over 3}) -t \sin({{2 \pi i} \over 3})$, hence we must have $t=-i$.

Substituting and multiplying shows that $T$ satisfies the second equation (noting that $e^{{{4 \pi i} \over 3}} = e^{-{{2 \pi i} \over 3}}$).

As noted above, any non zero multiple of $T$ is a solution.